# How to setup Rest API in google analytics and configure all endpoints with google console in .net

Tags: google-analytics, google-developers-console

I am trying to monitor my RestAPI trafic but i don't know how? I am a beginner(Junior developer) most of solutions show client side solution but in my project I don't have any html file. Can anyone guide how iI can configure google analytics with my API at server side.

Comment: Wlecome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic number 4 **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**

Comment: I have tried following solutions..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397907/tracking-asp-net-web-api-with-google-analytics/29571709     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653239/manually-sending-data-to-google-analytics and also tried some console application solution and read documentation of google analytics Measurement Protocol but I am unable to understand properly. I am confused because I don't know where I should put the tracking id in my API because in client side we can put under head tag.

Comment: I want to monitor API usage and most visited pages and hits count.